# Uploading chunked file to server from android

Tags: android, asp.net, upload, httpclient

I'm trying to send chunked file to an asp.net server from android. My client side code looks like this:

```
Public async Task<String> Upload(File file){
final int cSize = 1024 * 1024; // size of chunk
final long pieces = file.length()/cSize // used to return file length.

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(endpoint);

BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

for (int i= 0; i< pieces; i++) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[cSize];

    if(stream.read(buffer) ==-1)
      break;

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("chunk_id", new StringBody(String.valueOf(i))); //Chunk Id used for identification.
    request.setEntity(entity);
    ByteArrayInputStream arrayStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

    entity.addPart("file_data", new InputStreamBody(arrayStream, filename));

    HttpClient client = app.getHttpClient();
    client.execute(request);
}
```

What should the upload method look like on the server side? Do I have to initiate the connection to send each chunk or is it handled by MultipartEntity? Also is the method on the server side called again and again for each chunk upload?
I have tried to look for resources but couldn't find any that demonstrates how the chunked files is handled on the server side. I would really appreciate if someone can provide me any pointers.

Comment: To the person who downvoted my question. At least make an effort to answer the question before down voting it. This is extremely discouraging for beginners like me who're here to ask genuine questions because they couldn't find any helpful resource online..very sad

Comment: Are you uploading an image or video?

Comment: @user3151766 I'm uploading a video

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, your video should be sent  as a base64 string :

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("Base64MessageString");

string FileName = "FileName";

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

string FilePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\Video\\") + subPath + "\\";
string FullFilePath = FilePath + FileName;

FileInfo imageFile = new FileInfo(FullFilePath);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(FullFilePath, FileMode.Create);
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
ms.WriteTo(fs);
```

Comment: In this case there wont be any chunk. it will be a string in base64 format.